# Custom Data Source in RDLC file

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc

I created one RDLC file in which i use datatable for ReportDataSource but now i want use custom classinsted of data table please provird suggestion for this

```
 ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();



   reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1"; // Name of the DataSet we set in .rdlc

            reportDataSource.Value = dt;// Datatable 

            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = // Path of the rdlc file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new Report / Report Wizard to project and when adding data set in **Data Source Configuration Wizard** select **Object** and follow the wizard and select your data model and create your report.

Then put a report viewer on form and from smart tag windows (click little arrow at top right of report viewer) choose your report, you will see a `BindingSource` will add to the form, this binding source will be used as data source of report.

To pass data to your report, in Load event of form you can pass your `List<DataModel>` to the binding source and then `call this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();`

For more information you can take a look at:
[Walkthrough: Using a Business Object Data Source with the ReportViewer Windows Forms Control in Local Processing Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251784.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

First you must create data from your custom class.

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource
{
    Name = "DataSet1",
    Value = data
};
rpvAllReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource );
rpvAllReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = //your report Path
```

Then add parameter if you has

```
ReportParameter parameter1 = new ReportParameter("ParameterName1", parameter1Value);
rpvAllReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new[] { parameter1 });
rpvAllReportViewer.RefreshReport();
```